# Problemas com ascii ao rodar script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um script simples que precisa pegar os dados de um banco codificado em ascii, porem estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro referente a formatação utf-8.

trecho do codigo:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * from cadpro')
recset = cur.fetchall()
for rec in recset:
  print(rec)
```

mensagem de erro:

```
recset = cur.fetchall()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Você precisa colocar mais coisas nessa pergunta para que seja possível responder. Qual banco de dados é? Como é feita  a conexão? O seu banco não está em "ASCII puro", senão não teria esse caractere lá - ele pode ser um prefixo de um caractere em utf-8, mas pode ser também "Ç" se estiver codificado em latin-1.

Comment: Bom dia, Estou usando PostgreSQL e fazendo conexão com psycopg2, por padrão a instalação do banco dos clientes é selecionado o modelo como ASCII, a ideia do script é fazer alterações no banco utilizando comandos sql.